# TV series about an incoming end of the world. The characters think they can only save part of the world, possibly a hemisphere

Tags: story-identification, tv, apocalypse

I have some very vague memories about a TV series (I think) that I used to watch as a kid back in the late 90s/early 2000s (I'd say around 1995-2003). I don't really remember anything about it; the only important detail remaining in my memory is that the characters were making a big fuss over some incoming disaster, basically an end of the entire world. It was, however, stated very strongly that if they would meet some certain conditions, not all of the would would meet its doom, but "only" a northern part (a hemisphere perhaps...?) of it would cease to exist (or perhaps other way around, be spared). I guess preventing the disaster entirely was impossible and saving a part of it was already considered a success.

This was probably a series aimed for kids or young adults, because I doubt my parents would let me watch any serious stuff back then.

I know this isn't much. Does anybody remember something like this...?

Comment: Animated cartoon? Or live action?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_Zone

Comment: I think it was live action.

Comment: And was the disaster being dealt with throughout the series, or was it an establishing thing where the event happened in the first episode, and then they had to deal with it?

Comment: I don't remember, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the disaster happened in the framing of the first episode, *[The Girl from Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow)* had Alana, the title character, traveling to 1990 from the future of 3000, where they had lost the Northern hemisphere to "The Great Disaster" in 2500. In Season 2, Episode 11, "The Great Disaster Begins", they travel to 2500 to determine what caused the disaster, and there is indeed dialogue indicating that if the villain continues, the southern hemisphere will be lost as well (unfortunately, I can't actually watch the clip right now, so I can't fix the transcript).

> The peace platform has been destroyed, so how long
> do we wait till the end of the world? It
> will happen. I've seen it all there are no death rays or fire storms you've killed the northern hemisphere if you stop now the earth still has a chance

Comment: Yep, I think that's it. It seems that what I've remember is actually the second season.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/dMV5K-eG3mw?list=PLl48jMfth9b8EJwyFzCJ2GZ6w_fL4UAC5&t=719) sounds like a right moment, it's exactly what I've described: the world's is going to end but if the villain will be stopped only the northern hemisphere will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If it was in the early 2010s, it might be *[Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_(British_TV_series))*, a 2011 British series. You can view the trailer [here](https://www.traileraddict.com/ice/trailer).

> By 2020, global warming has increased significantly. Southern Europe has turned into a desert since it stopped raining, and similar events now happen in Northern Europe. Only the United Kingdom and some parts in the United States are unaffected. Furthermore, a global energy crisis exists as fossil fuels are running out. The last known reserves are under seabed under Greenland's glaciers. An American energy company, Halo, has the only licence to drill in Greenland.
>
> Professor Thom Archer works at "Polar Alliance", a government service, whose purpose is to find connections between industrial activities in the Arctic and the melting of its ice. Thom tries to convince the authorities to revoke the licence of Halo. According to Thom the glaciers are melting very fast, and if they disappear the sea water will rise 7 metres, the North Atlantic Current will halt, potentially causing a new ice age in the Northern Hemisphere. Halo admits there is indeed a heating in that area but also claims Thom has no evidence there is a direct connection between the heating and Halo's activities. Therefore the government extends the licence.
>
> As Thom's wife & daughter travel to visit his father in the UK for his daughter's birthday, Thom's colleague Peterson finds evidence that Halo's drills are responsible for the melting of the glaciers. Thom travels to Greenland only to find out Peterson was killed, apparently by a polar bear, but later determined to be at Halo's hand.
>
> Despite this, Thom finds Peterson's evidence, as a new drill by Halo opens a geothermic source in the seabed. This source melts down all the polar ice in only a few hours. Thom's prediction is now a fact: the northern hemisphere is rapidly covered by an enormous amount of snow and temperature decreases to -22° Fahrenheit.
>
> At Thom's insistence, the British Government advises the population to evacuate to the south, and they dismantle the apparatus of government. Meanwhile, Thom flies to the UK with ex-Halo environmental advocate Sarah Fitch, to rescue his family in a post-apocalyptic London.

Found with a search for `tv series disaster hemisphere`

Comment: That's not it, I was 21 when this premiered.

Comment: Ah. And when were you 21?

Comment: I was born in 1989. I watched the series in question as a kid so it should be somewhere around 1995-2003. 2011 is way too late.